# How to send object or data to controller from html file?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I get the "explorer" object in the html file and can analyze it:

```
<body>
<form th:action="@{/parsing}" method="post">
    <div class="w3-container">

        <table class="w3-table-all w3-card-4">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Query</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td th:text="${explorer.getId()}"></td>
                <td th:text="${explorer.getQuery()}"></td>
                <td>
                    <input class="w3-button w3-blue w3-right" type="submit" value="Enter"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to send it in post method but when I submit, I get null in "result".

Method, who get query from submit action:

```
@PostMapping("/parsing")
public ModelAndView parsing(
    @ModelAttribute Explorer explorer
    ){
    System.out.println("explorerId = " + explorer.getId());
    System.out.println("explorerId = " + explorer.getQuery());
    return new ModelAndView("result");
}
```

(It does not throw any exceptions, but prints only null data in the console)

How to send any object in this situation for post-method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Your form is missing a commanding object attribute.

I would suggest adding `th:object="${explorer}"` to your form tag.

In your `GET` method, double check the function to *create* the explorer object from controller and then add the object in request attribute for the form to command an object before a `POST` action can be successfully submit the object.

This [Thymeleaf docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html) has more answers than I could combine in this thread.